# Java ProcessBuilder: Input/Output Stream

Tags: java, outputstream, processbuilder

I want to invoke an external program in java code, then the Google tell me that the Runtime or ProcessBuilder can help me to do this work. I have tried it, and there come out a problem the java program can't exit, that means both the sub process and the father process wait for forever. they are hanging or deadlock.

Someone tell me the reason is that the sub process's cache is too small. when it try to give back data to the father process, but the father process don't read it in time, then both of them hang. So they advice me fork an thread to be in charge of read sub process's cache data. I do it as what they tell me, but there still some problem.

Then I close the output stream which get by the method getOutputStream(). Finally, the program success. But I don't know why it happen? Is there some relationship between the output steam and input stream?

Comment: What external program are you trying to run?  Can you run this program in a command-prompt/Terminal/shell?

Comment: This answer helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14168097

Answer (score 23):

You have provided very few details in your question, so I can only provide a general answer.

All processes have three standard streams: standard input, standard output and standard error.  Standard input is used for reading in data, standard output for writing out data, and standard error for writing out error messages.  When you start an external program using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` or `ProcessBuilder`, Java will create a `Process` object for the external program, and this `Process` object will have methods to access these streams.

These streams are accessed as follows:

- `process.getOutputStream()`: return the **standard input** of the external program.  This is an `OutputStream` as it is something your Java code will write to.
- `process.getInputStream()`: return the **standard output** of the external program.  This is an `InputStream` as it is something your Java code will read from.
- `process.getErrorStream()`: return the standard error of the external program.  This is an `InputStream` as, like standard output, it is something your Java code will read from.

Note that the names of `getInputStream()` and `getOutputStream()` can be confusing.

All streams between your Java code and the external program are *buffered*.  This means each stream has a small amount of memory (a *buffer*) where the writer can write data that is yet to be read by the reader.  The writer does not have to wait for the reader to read its data immediately; it can leave its output in the buffer and continue.

There are two ways in which writing to buffers and reading from them can hang:

- attempting to write data to a buffer when there is not enough space left for the data,
- attempting to read from an empty buffer.

In the first situation, the writer will wait until space is made in the buffer by reading data out of it.  In the second, the reader will wait until data is written into the buffer.

You mention that closing the stream returned by `getOutputStream()` caused your program to complete successfully.  This closes the **standard input** of the external program, telling it that there will be nothing more for it to read.  If your program then completes successfully, this suggests that your program was waiting for more input to come when it was hanging.

It is perhaps arguable that if you do run an external program, you should close its standard input if you don't need to use it, as you have done.  This tells the external program that there will be no more input, and so removes the possibility of it being stuck waiting for input.  However, it doesn't answer the question of why your external program is waiting for input.

Most of the time, when you run external programs using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` or `ProcessBuilder`, you don't often use the standard input.  Typically, you'd pass whatever inputs you'd need to the external program on the command line and then read its output (if it generates any at all).

Does your external program do what you need it to and then get stuck, apparently waiting for input?  Do you ever need to send it data to its standard input?  If you start a process on Windows using `cmd.exe /k ...`, the command interpreter will continue even after the program it started has exited.  In this case, you should use `/c` instead of `/k`.

Finally, I'd like to emphasise that there are two output streams, standard output and standard error.  There can be problems if you read from the wrong stream at the wrong time.  If you attempt to read from the external program's standard output while its buffer is empty, your Java code will wait for the external program to generate output.  However, if your external program is writing a lot of data to its standard error, it could fill the buffer and then find itself waiting for your Java code to make space in the buffer by reading from it.  The end result of this is your Java code and the external program are both waiting for each other to do something, i.e. deadlock.

This problem can be eliminated simply by using a `ProcessBuilder` and ensuring that you call its `redirectErrorStream()` method with a `true` value.  Calling this method redirects the standard error of the external program into its standard output, so you only have one stream to read from.