# Running java programs inside a java program

Tags: java

Hi guys I want to run java programs inside my javaprogram.

However when I tried to execute java command it tells me this:

> java c:\works\Sample stderr: Error: Could not find or load main class
>   c:\works\Sample

This is my code:

```
private void runButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        Processor p = new Processor();
        try {
            int k = p.runProcess("javac c:\\works\\Sample.java");
            if (k == 0) {       
                k = p.runProcess("java c:\\works\\Sample");
            }

            System.out.println("Value of k: " + k);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is my Processor Class

```
public class Processor {

public void printLines(String name, InputStream ins) throws Exception {
    String line = null;
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(ins));
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(name + " " + line);
    }
}

public int runProcess(String command) throws Exception {


    Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    printLines(command + " stdout:", pro.getInputStream());
    printLines(command + " stderr:", pro.getErrorStream());
    pro.waitFor();
    // System.out.println(command + " exitValue() " + pro.exitValue());
    return pro.exitValue();
}
```

}

My files were under "C:\works\"

Your responses would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `java` is different than `javac`. One of basic differences it that it expects `full.package.name.of.YourClass`, not `c:/location/of/YourClass`. Also it expects in its classpatch parameter location of package with class you want to run.

Comment: What If i have no package?

Comment: under works folder were the .class file and .java file. Only two files there.

Comment: use `java -cp locationODirectoryHoldingfYourClassWithoutPackage YourClass`

Comment: ^that worked! but it writes on my console only. What IF i want it to appear on CMD itself?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "my console only" and "on CMD itself".

Comment: Ok, I run those codes in an IDE. And the output was in System.out.println(). What If I clicked the button the CMD showed up then theres the output?

Comment: I am still unsure what you mean. Also "And the output was in System.out.println()." doesn't seem right because `println` simply passes data to print, it doesn't decide where to print it (by default it is console from which our command was started/run).

Comment: Why not call the class directly?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by having one master program which you run from your CMD which runs whatever processes you want and redirect input/output of these processes to its own input/output which happens to be your CMD input/output.
Here is good [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573457/java-processbuilder-input-output-stream).